# Check which mouse button was "upped"

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

Well, I have an event handler for when a mouse button is up. I want to check which button was (left or right). This is the function definition:

```
 Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseUp
```

I used

```
    e.Button.Left()
```

to try to get a boolean, but I get an error....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [button property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.button.aspx)

```
If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then
    'Do Somthing
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.button.aspx